# NiFi dynamic attributes usage

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm sending requests via ListenHttp processor, for example

```
curl -X POST --data "myschema.mytable" http://localhost:44221/contentListener
```

how can I then use that in my DB query?

I want to execute in the ExecuteSQL processor `select * from myschema.mytable`

Comment: `myschema.mytable` should appear in flow file content. possible to use replacetext to convert content to desired query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written by @daggett in the comments, the body of the post request is written to the FlowFile content.

You may extract the FlowFile content into an attribute using the *ExtractText* processor.
In case the whole request body consists of the table name you may use `(.+)` as RegEx to store it in an FlowFile attribute, as seen below.

[image]

This will result in the whole content being written to the defined attribute.

[image]

To prevent you from being vulnerable against SQL injection you should escape any user based input in your queries. Thus instead of executing `select * from myschema.mytable` you should rather use `select * from ?` as query.

To let the *ExecuteSQL* processor known what to escape and insert instead of the question mark, you must add two attributes - `sql.args.1.type` and `sql.args.1.value` - to your FlowFile *before* sending it to the ExecuteSQL processor.

You may use an *UpdateAttribute* processor to do so. The type varchar is resembled by the number 12. To find out the correct mappings consult [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types).

[image]
[image]

You then may use it as part of your SQL-Query inside the *ExecuteSQL* processor.

[image]

**Remarks**

You should be aware of potential out-of-memory errors in case the content of the post requests gets to large. In general it is NOT recommended to store the whole content as attribute as attributes are generally stored in memory. In case you are able to alter the http request signature I recommend you to use a common format - e.g. JSON - and only extract the wanted value using a corresponding processor instead of ExtractText.

#### Providing the variable as HTTP header

As suggested by @mattyb in the comments, instead of using the body of a POST request you could also provide the value as HTTP header and read it from there.
That way you may remove the *ReplaceText* processor entirely.

To do so you may alter the request to something along the lines of:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:31337/contentListener \
  --header 'databaseName: nyan.cat'
```

Inside the *ListenHttp* processor you have to set the value `^databaseName$` for the *HTTP Headers to receive as Attributes (Regex)* property.

This will result in the attribute databaseName being set as with the previous approach.

Comment: Might be easier (if possible for your use case) to send the table name as a header instead of data. If you set the `HTTP Headers to receive as Attributes (Regex)` property to `tableName` and then send `tableName: myschema.mytable` as a header in the `curl` command, then after ListenHttp it will already be in a flow file attribute so you can skip the ExtractText processor

Comment: @mattyb I added a paragraph explaining the approach you suggested. Thanks.